# CSS: div padding according to responsive image in background

Tags: css, less

I have a parent div which has a background image of mountains.
I have a child div which have a responsive image of houses.
I want to give a padding-top to child div when vertical width of window changes, so that houses will keep their position at bottom of the mountains.
I am  using less css.

Comment: Post your code you have so far

Answer (score 2):

Wouldn't it be better if you applied `position: absolute; bottom: 0` to the houses, and mountain will have `position: relative`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go ahead and preface this with "I'm definitely not the best at CSS" but I'm reasonably certain the effect you want could be achieved with using the [Viewport Height](https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/)

Here's a quick snippet below. You may want to change from `vh` to maybe `vmin` or `vmax`, depending.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
.parent {
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/400x600);
  height: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.child {
  padding-top: 10vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    Testing
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Background image is responsive so mountain position changes when vertical width change, I want to keep the houses at the same position (where mountain ends) One way is that I can use media queries for every 100px or so and define padding-top, but I want to use a formula so to keep the media queries at minimum.

Answer (score 0):

If by vertical width you mean height, you have to do it with js
jQuery exaple

```
if ($(window).height()) < 800 {
    $(childdiv).css('pading-top','60px');
}
```